# onActivityResult() not called in fragment when using startResolutionForResult();

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, gps

Open a `GPS dialog` in fragment when GPS is disabled but when I click on the button "OK" and " Cancel" then `OnActivityResult()` not call in the fragment.

Can anyone guide me regarding this problem??
this problem occurs only in fragment but not in activity.

```
 public void openGpsDialog() {
     PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                        // requests here.

                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.

                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(
                                    homeActivity, REQUEST_LOCATION);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }
        });             }
```

**onActivityResult()**

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    final LocationSettingsStates states = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_LOCATION:
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "gps enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: did u try `getActivity().startResolutionForResult();` it will call onActivityResult()  or if u want to invoke fragment OnActivityForResult than remove ` super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` and call as u r calling

Comment: try dont call super

Comment: i have try this but no response occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have passed activity object with Intent so result will be return in Activity not in fragment

```
status.startResolutionForResult(homeActivity, REQUEST_LOCATION);
```

Simple solution is pass your response from activity to fragment

Activity Code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.dualPane);
    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

OR

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    for (Fragment fragment : getChildFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , but i am using viewpager and set fragment on viewpager using FragmentPagerAdaptor ,

Comment: So how can i set fragment id